# currency symbol replace specific

Tags: woocommerce, currency, symbols

I am developing a new woocommerce site, and faced a new issue that I have not dealed with in other shops. I need to change the currency symbol to something else than the standard. In my country it's DKK. And my custom text should be "DKK / month" but only in the cart(product loop overview), not in total calculation(checkout section), because, for example, freight is not / month and totals is not either.

Following code is working great everywhere on the page, but it needs to be only in the cart listing/loop pr. product, and also btw in the reciept product listing.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'DKK': $currency_symbol = 'kr. <span class="paymentType">/ month</span>'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

How do i change that to only appear at cart product loop?

I have tried with:

```
if(is_cart()){
    add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

    function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
         switch( $currency ) {
              case 'DKK': $currency_symbol = 'kr. <span class="paymentType">/ month</span>'; break;
         }
         return $currency_symbol;
    }
}
```

But is not working, and I am not sure that's it is the right approach.
Suggestions? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with above I ended up manually typing / month in the various template files (not core files) where the price was defined. Hope this will help someone else :)